# Как скрыть товары из каталога по категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скрыть товар конкретной категории из каталога товаров? Пробовал так - не работает:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products', 25 );
function hide_products( $query ) {
    $tax_query = (array) $query->get( 'tax_query' );
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'snyato-s-proizvodstva' ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
}
?>
```

upd: выполнению кода мешает плагин product Filter от mihajlovicnenad.

Comment: Код с виду правильный. Я проверил на тестовом сайте - работает. Видимо, слаг указан неверно (`snyato-s-proizvodstva`) или есть ещё аналогичный фильтр с большим приоритетом. Поставьте `PHP_INT_MAX` вместо `25`.

Comment: Понял, что выполнению кода мешает плагин Product Filter от mihajlovicnenad. Но PHP_INT_MAX, не помогает. Может быть как-то можно по-другому увеличить приоритет выполнения кода?

Comment: Выше уже некуда )) Надо ковырять код плагина, что он там творит. Добавьте замечание о плагине в вопрос.